# Decreasing opacity of other menus on mouseover of one menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three parent menus: menu 1 ,menu 2 and menu 3. On mousehover of menu 1, I need to decrease the opacity of other menus. Also the menu items of menu 1 should be shown. My goal is to make something as shown in the screenshot. A simple example is enough for me. I will modify it accordingly.

[image]

Here is my fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/sruthisuresh/y2danw9h/3/

```css
nav ul {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-table;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #888888;
}
nav ul > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul > li:hover {
  background: #665c5c;
}
nav ul li a {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #302e2e;
  display: block;
}
nav ul ul {
  width: 200px;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
nav ul ul li a {
  background: #665c5c;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">PHP</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">User Experience</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Where are the _MENUS_ ?

Comment: my goal is to make something as shown in the screenshot..a simple example is enough for me.I will modify it accordingly.

Comment: Will you mind posting a simple example which is not working as expected ?

Comment: You'll want to use js to affect other elements. Something like this I think:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this using css only is to lower the opacity of all `li`-elements while hovering on the `ul`.
And then restore the opacity on the currently hovered `li`.

You can do this by adding this code.

```
nav ul:hover > li {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Full Example**

```css
nav ul {
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-table;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #888888;
}

nav ul > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul:hover > li:not(:hover){
  -webkit-transition: .7s;
  -moz-transition: .7s;
  transition: .7s;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul > li:hover {
  background: #665c5c;
}

nav ul:hover > li {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #302e2e;
  display: block;
}

nav ul ul {
  width: 200px;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  background: #665c5c;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Glad to be at help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery try this:

```
$(".menu").mouseover(function(){
    $(".menu").css("opacity",0.2);
    $(this).css("opacity",1);
})
```

where "menu" is the class for all the menus you want to lower opacity to 0.2
The next line will set the opacity of the current menu to 1.

You should also have a similar block for `$(".menu").mouseleave(....)`

```
$(".menu").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".menu").css("opacity",1);
})
```

Comment: thank you for your effort..but am not using any JQuery currently..i have added my fidlle here.can you have a look at it..

Comment: this also worked for me.I made some modifications and  used J Query. It worked.Thanks R. Schifini.